# Long beeps and PC died

Tags: motherboard, boot

My PC has a Gigabyte GA-M57SLI-S4 motherboard. While I was on Debian the motherboard started to beep (1 long beep) and it switched itself off. Then I was not able to boot. There is no signal going to the monitor. I cleaned the RAM sockets and reinstalled them, rechecked and reinstalled the graphics card, rechecked and reinstalled HDD power and SATA cables, but nothing! Now it doesn't even beep.

PS: these are the beep codes from the motherboard's manual:

> AWARD BIOS Beep Codes
>
> 1 short: System boots successfully
>   2 short: CMOS setting error
>   1 long 1 short: DRAM or M/B error
>   1 long 2 short: Monitor or display card error
>   1 long 3 short: Keyboard error
>   1 long 9 short: BIOS ROM error
>   **Continuous long beeps: DRAM error**
>   Continuous short beeps: Power error

Comment: DUDE, beeps are codes, IBM Beep codes. So count how many beeps besides whether they are long or short. they are IBM Beep codes.

Comment: it was 1 long beep (looping)

Comment: according to this, on an ibm desktop  http://www.bioscentral.com/beepcodes/ibmbeep.htm  one continuous beep means a power supply error, have you tried changing the psu?  and on an ibm thinkpad it means a system board error

Comment: no but i am gonna buy one tomorrow. PSU's fans spin though.

Comment: @barlop, DUDE, BIOS beep codes only apply when booting, not when the system is already running the OS. And they said it no longer beeps after rebooting, so it’s probably something else.

Comment: @Synetech - The beeps within the operating likely indicated a i/o error I have encountered them when I was running Windows on a hdd with several dozen bad sectors.  I am worried about the fact it no longer even trys to POST, that indicates a short, which is not good.

Comment: @Ramhound, well they said they were using Ubuntu, so I don’t know what (if anything) beeps mean in that. Personally, I have heard beeps while up and running in a few scenarios like when my keyboard was connected badly, when some high-priority program was locking up the CPU for a period of time, or when some other hardware issue was causing trouble. Yes, that it won’t POST is definitely a bad sign.

Comment: @Synetech - I don't know if Ubuntu as a general i/o sound, Windows, you get that when the CPU is basically deadlocked ( happens if you queue so many i/o requests ) and its waiting on responses from your hdd.  But those are short beeps.  The long beep literally could have been the CPU failing.

Comment: I didn't notice you were saying the beep was within the OS, those BIOS beep codes don't apply there. But you should try changing things you haven't changed anyway, like PSU etc.

Comment: Also, try taking out the RAM modules and putting in just a single stick; if it doesn’t work, try it in the next slot, then repeat for each slot, then repeat for each RAM stick. If it works in any combination, then one (or more) of the sticks is bad. If it *never* works, see what happens with *no* RAM installed (it should give the appropriate beep code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the culprit! Apparently it was indeed the RAM sockets!

The beep returned (somehow) so I started to re-check all sockets...still beep!
Then I went ahead and re-tried the RAM sticks one by one...still beep!
(then took a smoke break and for the last time re-tried plugging in/out GPU and RAM sticks before going ahead to re-paste the CPU)

Bam! this time magically the beep went away and the PC booted with RAM in socket #3 (didn't work before)!

My guess and conclusion: There is a nasty random short-circuit affecting all of the RAM sockets. I'd better start looking for a new motherboard.

Comment: You should always be clear where the beep occurred 'cos earlier you spoke of a beep within the OS, and at other times a BIOS beep code.  You should be clearer on that when you write of a beep. (I do see now you're talking of BIOS beeps).

Comment: Maybe you didn't seat the RAM properly the last time. it's premature to say it's the motherboard. just go with it being the ram not being seated right perhaps. And the beep within the OS may just be a mysetery. though no harm in changing the motherboard!

Comment: My bet is badly seated ram. I've had that myself quite a few times

Answer (score -2):

Your processor could be overheating and is shutting down. You need to take out the fan and heatsink and reapply the thermal paste. That or check that your box is getting adequate cooling.

Good luck.

Comment: the CPU core temperatures were fine before the PC "died".

Comment: @sterz - I would go ahead and try this despite you thinking it wasn't happening it might have happen.